# How to load jquery and other library files locally from server and not from c0.wp.com? Wordpress / PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

Because of some privacy law stuff, I need to save libraries and stuff (which come from server from USA) locally on my server and load it from there.
I saw jquery and other stuff is loaded from c0.wp.com. Is there a way to change the wordpress code so that I can load it locally?
I already did that for jquery:

```
function include_custom_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_custom_jquery');
```

But somehow I get errors thrown now from the theme files:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    load jQuery
    <anonymous> http://testsite.test/wp-content/themes/parentthemename/js/core.min.js?ver=5.9.3:40
```

I am not sure why is that? Or is there a different way?

Comment: Is that Question not related to PHP? Because your Code is (I guess) from a functions.php file of a WordpressTheme.

Comment: @grisuu yes! added the tag